# Particle motion and frenet frame

Tags: differential-geometry, frenet-frame

I am given that $\hat{t}=\dfrac{\hat{x}+y'\hat{y}}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}$ and $\hat{n}=\dfrac{y'\hat{x}-\hat{y}}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}$ are the tangential and normal vector in frenet frame. We are considering only 2 dimensional case, where a particle moves along a curve.

Then the author state a equation (second law of motion)
${\vec{F}}=mv\left(\dfrac{dv}{ds}\hat{t}+v\dfrac{d\hat{t}}{ds}\right)=mv\dfrac{dv}{ds}\hat{t}+mv^2\kappa \hat{n}$, which i am able to understand how it comes.

However afterwards, the author defines (Kinetic energy) $K=\frac12mv^2(x,y)$ and claims that $\vec{F}=\nabla K$ I am not able to arrive at the normal $\hat{n}$ component of the result. Can anyone help me and also is there a gradient operator in terms of frenet frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simplify,

\begin{align*}
  dW &= \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r} \\
     &= \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{T} \, ds \\\
     &= mv \, dv
\end{align*}

Comment: Sorry, I am kinda not able to understand how to utilize that.

Comment: Do you know $\mathbf{F}=-\nabla U=\nabla K \iff \Delta K=\int_{C} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r}$?

Comment: Oh sorry, I know that but I actually wanted to take gradient of $\frac12 mv^2$ to arrive at the result $mv\dfrac{dv}{ds}\hat{t}+mv^2\kappa \hat{n}$

Comment: That's rather strange, we usually using $\mathbf{F}=-\nabla U(x,y)$ and $\displaystyle \mathbf{v}=\frac{\partial K}{\partial \mathbf{p}}$

Comment: http://academics.smcvt.edu/abrizard/Classical_Mechanics/Notes_070707.pdf

Page 32 and 33

Comment: After looking the whole paragraph, I think the line in equation (2.4) is component extraction rather than logical derivation.  $\mathbf{F}=\nabla K=\mathbf{T} (\mathbf{T} \cdot \nabla K)+\mathbf{N} (\mathbf{N} \cdot \nabla K)$ so $mv^2 \kappa=\mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{N}$

Comment: Yes i am kinda confused with that, I just don't get how did he claim $F=\nabla K$ rest i kind of understood.

Comment: Note that $mv^2 \kappa$ is simply the centripetal force.